# Http Call from android from Rest API

Tags: android, django, http

How do I get rest api data that I created using Django's rest framework? Also just for the information I am not being able to access this link from my android phone browser either so quiet obviously if I do a volley /http reqest it won't do anything.

[image]

Comment: Hi Shayekh - you really may need to add a whole lot more information here. Is your DRF site in production...if so it should have endpoints you can call with various HTTP requests (e.g., "POST", "GET", "DELETE" etc). This question will likely get flagged very quickly.

Comment: Its just a project. That I am doing. And I am not really sure how to make the call with android. I can't seem to find a way out.

Comment: You'd need some sort of HTTP request library in whichever language/framework you're using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To request rest Apis in android you can use a library called “RETROFIT” 
Please checkout their documentation and you can see a lot of tutorials on retrofit.

Also, if you haven’t deployed your drf based django project to a production/live server you will not be able to request and receive responses from your apis,

Also another tool for testing your apis is POSTMAN. Its a chrome app which can request and show you responses from apis.

Since you are trying to request using volley and it isnt working, it must be that you havent deployed the django app and you are still using a development server,

In that case
Run the server using

```
Python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And then find your machines ip address, using

```
ifconfig or ipconfig (depends on ur OS)
```

And once you get it, use that ip as your base url for the api and connect your android phone used for testing the api into the same network where your machine running django is connected to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, means a lot.  And yes I finally got the server to work and request from my android phone however encountered another problem I guess I'll have to post another post. Btw, thanks a lot the Python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 thing, was the breakthough I needed.

Comment: Happy to have helped you, you can also change the ports and call to different ports using 0.0.0.0